# I can Activate my Windows 7 Ultimate on 2 PCs, why?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I couldn't find the 3rd box of Windows 7 Ultimate that I bought, so I tried using the 2nd box which I already used for activating Win 7 on my Notebook computer...

Strangely, it says Activation successful... (on the desktop computer)  and my Win 7 Ultimate is not a family pack... so how come it can be activated on two PCs?

Comment: Windows can be activated more than once.  Even when that fails you can still call up Microsoft and they can give you a number to type in by activating over the phone.  The main idea is that people will have to re-install their computer and it would be a PR nightmare to only allow you to install Windows once.  Maybe I upgraded to a new computer and trashed my old one.

Comment: Give it a few days, and one of them will start to consider itself nonlegit.

Comment: are you sure...?  you are talking as if it will recheck?

Answer (score 1):

Probably to save money on support calls when a person has to do a reinstall from scratch. When we purchased a single license of Windows 7 through our Volume License agreement, we got a MAK  that would activate 50 copies of Windows 7.

Just cause it works doesn't make it legit.

Comment: As long as he owns 3 copies hes fine. Microsoft doesn't care so much about which copies are activated as much as if the users owns enough licenses.

Comment: I wasn't intending to make the case that he was or wasn't acting improper. My point is only that Microsoft does allow extra activations in different circumstances.